# Child Control Node.position and global_position both locked at (0.0, 0.0)?

Tags: godot, godot4

I made this just as a test case for a more complex problem I'm working on. Same issue:

```
extends GridContainer

@onready var color_rect_8 := $ColorRect8 #ColorRect8 is the 8th colorrect in the grid

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    if color_rect_8.is_inside_tree():
        print_position()


func print_position() -> void:
    print(color_rect_8.position)
    print(color_rect_8.global_position)
```

It seems like all controls, everywhere, print their local and global_position to (0, 0). TO clarify, color_rect_8's position in the inspector is (0, 467) in this instance.
And if I were to add a node2d(for example) as a child of the root node, then set its position to color_rect_8's global_position, the node2d will still just appear in the top left corner.

I've tried this with a few different control nodes in different combinations, and it seems the result is the same every time. I honestly have no idea what's going on. Any idea what's up?

Comment: This is a strange problem. Have you tried using the ``to_global`` method? https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html#class-node2d-method-to-global